# TeeChart cannot load my custom properties using LoadChartFromStream

Tags: delphi-xe5, teechart

`LoadChartFromStream` causes an exception when `SaveChartToStream` has saved some of my custom properties.

It crashes with "property MyCoolProperty does not exist".

```
type
  TMyChart = class(TChart)
  strict private
    MyCoolProperty: Integer;
  published
    property MyCoolProperty: Integer read FMyCoolProperty write FMyCoolProperty;
  end;

Chart, CopyChart: TMyChart;

MStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  SaveChartToStream(Chart, MStream, False, False);
  MStream.Position := 0;
  LoadChartFromStream(TCustomChart(CopyChart), MStream);
finally
  MStream.Free;
end;
```

How to make `LoadChartFromStream` ignore properties that it cannot cope with and load properties that it can load without breaking the whole because of one small part?

Answer (score 1):

Let me copy the reply from [here](https://www.steema.com/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15986&p=70948), where a similar issue was addressed

> Have you tried overriding `DefineProperties` and adding there the properties to serialize?
> This works fine for me here:
>
> ```pascal
> uses TeeStore;
>
> type TMyBarSeries = class(TBarSeries)
>   private
>     procedure WriteBarName(Writer: TWriter);
>     procedure ReadBarName(Reader: TReader);
>     procedure WriteBarID(Writer: TWriter);
>     procedure ReadBarID(Reader: TReader);
>
>   protected
>     IBarNameStored: boolean;
>     IBarName: string;
>     IBarID: Integer;
>
>     procedure DefineProperties(Filer:TFiler); override;
>
>   public
>     property BarName: string read IBarName write IBarName stored IBarNameStored;
>     property BarID: Integer read IBarID write IBarID default -1;
> end;
>
> procedure TMyBarSeries.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); 
> begin
>   inherited;  
>   Filer.DefineProperty('BarName',ReadBarName,WriteBarName,True);  
>   Filer.DefineProperty('BarID',ReadBarID,WriteBarID,True); 
> end;
>
> procedure TMyBarSeries.WriteBarName(Writer: TWriter); 
> begin
>   Writer.WriteIdent(BarName); 
> end;
>
> procedure TMyBarSeries.ReadBarName(Reader: TReader); 
> begin
>   BarName:=Reader.ReadIdent;
> end;
>
> procedure TMyBarSeries.WriteBarID(Writer: TWriter);
> begin
>   Writer.WriteInteger(BarID);
> end;
>
> procedure TMyBarSeries.ReadBarID(Reader: TReader);
> begin
>   BarID:=Reader.ReadInteger;
> end;
>
> procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
> var memStream1: TStream;
> begin   
>   RegisterClass(TMyBarSeries);
>
>   Chart1.View3D:=false;   
>   Chart1.Legend.Visible:=false;
>
>   with Chart1.AddSeries(TMyBarSeries) as TMyBarSeries do
>   begin
>     BarID:=1;
>     BarName:='MyBar #' + IntToStr(BarID);
>     FillSampleValues;
>     ColorEachPoint:=true;
>   end;
>
>   memStream1:=TMemoryStream.Create;
>   SaveChartToStream(Chart1, memStream1);
>
>   memStream1.Position:=0;
>   LoadChartFromStream(Chart2, memStream1);
>
>   Chart2.Top:=Chart1.Top+Chart1.Height+10;
>
>   Memo1.Clear;
>   Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr((Chart1[0] as TMyBarSeries).BarID));
>   Memo1.Lines.Add((Chart1[0] as TMyBarSeries).BarName);
>
>   Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr((Chart2[0] as TMyBarSeries).BarID));  
>   Memo1.Lines.Add((Chart2[0] as TMyBarSeries).BarName);
> end;
> ```